# What does the MetavarTypeHelpFormatter in Python argparse mean?

Tags: python, argparse

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
prog='PROG',
formatter_class=argparse.MetavarTypeHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=int)
parser.add_argument('bar', type=float)
parser.print_help()
```

What is metavar?

What does the MetavarTypeHelpFormatter do?

Under what circumstances we are using metavar?

Comment: BTW i'm new to stackoverflow, how can I put a newline before text

Comment: Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.MetavarTypeHelpFormatter): *"`MetavarTypeHelpFormatter` uses the name of the type argument for each argument as the display name for its values (rather than using the dest as the regular formatter does)"* - [`metavar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar), [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type). There are also examples showing the output when using it.

Comment: FYI: 2 spaces at the end of a line forces a linebreak, see [formatting->Linebreaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help that you forgot to show:

```
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo int] float

positional arguments:
  float

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo int
```

See the `int` and `float` words?  They match the `type` parameters.

The help without the special formatter_class:

```
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo FOO] bar

positional arguments:
  bar

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO
```

`FOO` and `bar` instead.

With explicit `metavar`:

```
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=int, metavar='anInt')
parser.add_argument('bar', type=float, metavar='aFloat')

usage: PROG [-h] [--foo anInt] aFloat

positional arguments:
  aFloat

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --foo anInt
```